# Implement Thread in my class?

Tags: java, android, xml, root

I would like to know how to implement a thread in this class to make it safe from the problems of ANR (Application Not Responding)

```
public class myClass {


    private static String LOG_TAG = Root.class.getName();

    public boolean isDeviceRooted() throws IOException {

        if (checkRootMethod1()){return true;}
        if (checkRootMethod2()){return true;}
        if (checkRootMethod3()){return true;}
        return false;

    }
    public boolean checkRootMethod1(){
        String buildTags = android.os.Build.TAGS;

        if (buildTags != null && buildTags.contains("test-keys")) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public boolean checkRootMethod2(){
        try {
            File file = new File("/system/app/Superuser.apk");
            if (file.exists()) {
                return true;
            }
            else {

                return false;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

        return false;
    }

    public boolean checkRootMethod3() {
        if (new ExecShell().executeCommand(SHELL_CMD.check_su_binary) != null){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }


            }
```

If for example this code is execute when i press a button, if i press many times this button, my app have an ANR.

Comment: Seriously?  You ask a question, then repeat it in 10 minutes?  That must be a record!

Comment: I'm sorry, I have problems with the internet connection.

Answer (score 0):

You should make something like this:

```
new Thread(new Runnable(){ 
  @Override
  public void run(){
   boolean isRooted = isDeviceRooted();
   rootedListener.isDeviceRooted(isRooted);
  }
}
```

Then declare a listener to get the asynchronous response